# Clear Only Row-Level Errors in Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, error-messages

I'm trying to do `datatable` error-handling using the built-in `errors` attribute. For the sake of example, let's say I have a datatable like this:

```
<lightning-datatable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    key-field="id"
    errors={errors}
    draft-values={draftValues}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

I can set row-level and table-level errors just fine, like this:

```
this.errors = {
  rows: {
    '1': {
      title: 'Validation Error',
      messages: ['some error'],
      fieldNames: ['someField']
    }
  },
  table: {
    title: 'Table-Level Error',
    messages: ['There was an error on the table!']
  }
};
```

And I can clear out ***all*** errors (table-level and row-level) by simply doing this:

```
this.errors = null;
```

But nothing happens if I try to clear just the table-level errors or just the row-level errors, like this:

```
this.errors.table = null;
```

Or this:

```
this.errors.rows = null;
```

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround? [Here's a working sample](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/UYg7WGQyvYxmtrV038IP).

Answer (score 2):

You need to either track the variable, or you need to refresh it with a copy.

## Track

This mode lets LWC inspect for deep changes to objects. Use this when you need it, but remember it affects rendering time, so also use it sparingly.

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc'
```

...

```
@track errors
```

## Object Copy

When you update the top-level object, it causes an inspection to occur.

```
this.errors.table = null;
this.errors = {...this.errors}
```